# Get fileName into Textbox before Loading Form1

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with **Drag and Drop** file Code, I try many methods but I failed this is my Code.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim pathstring As String
        If args.Length > 0 Then
            Dim path = args(0)
            pathstring = path

        End If
    End Sub
End Module
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = pathstring
    End Sub
End Class
```

Above Code working fine with Console Application, but not in WindowsApplication
I want to get filename into **Textbox1 Control** before loading **Form**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how WinForms apps work. That `Main` method isn't even being executed because it's not the entry point for the app. Unless you disable the Application Framework, you need to handle the app's `Startup` event if you want to do something before creating the startup form. That said, you can get the commandline arguments anywhere, any time by calling `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.

Comment: many Thanks for reply but can you show me a example  how is to work Environment.GetCommandLineArgs ? i dont want to disable  Application Framework

Comment: i try this code but filename i got ...WindowsApplication1.exe
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim pathstring As String

        Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        If args.Length > 0 Then

            Dim path = args(0)
            pathstring = path
            TextBox1.Text = pathstring
        End If


    End Sub

Comment: I expect that there would be literally hundreds of examples of the use of that method on the web. That said, why do you need two variables to get a value from an array into a `TextBox`? Why do you need `path` or `pathstring` at all? Why can't you just assign the appropriate array element to the `Text` of the `TextBox` directly? Also, you clearly haven't bothered to read about that method if you're looking at the first element of the array. You're allowed to do some research/reading of your own you know. You could even use the debugger to examine the array.

Comment: jmcilhinney Thanks i research some web now i got my working code 
  Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

            Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
            If args.Length > 0 Then
                Dim path = args(1)
                Form1.TextBox1.Text = path
            End If

        End Sub 
and this is too  
 For Each i In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString)
            Next

Comment: That code still isn't right. You are getting the correct array element, i.e. the second one, but you're still testing whether the `Length` of the array is greater than zero. That will ALWAYS be true because the first element is always the app path itself.